# How to call a console command in web application action in Yii?

Tags: yii, console-application

I have a console command to do a consumer time, AND I need to know how to call (execute) it in a web application action in YII.

```
class MyCommand extends CConsoleCommand{
      public function actionIndex(){
          $model = new Product();
          $model->title = 'my product';
          ...
          $model->save();
          .
          .
          .
      }
}
```

I want to execute this code.

Comment: Why do you want this to be a command and not a controller?

Comment: it's a sample code. I just mentioned that i need run a command action in a web action.

Comment: But the purpose of a Command it's to run offline tasks, so ju can use it with a cron job.

Comment: Indeed i need to create some 16bits number random, and insert theme in a table, because it takes too long i get maximum limit time execution error. and i need do that some way else.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

try this:

```
    Yii::import('application.commands.*');
    $command = new MyCommand("test", "test");
    $command->run(null);
```

The 2 parameters with value "test" must be set but do not have an impact, they are used for the --help option when using the console.

```
/**
 * Constructor.
 * @param string $name name of the command
 * @param CConsoleCommandRunner $runner the command runner
 */
public function __construct($name,$runner)
{
    $this->_name=$name;
    $this->_runner=$runner;
    $this->attachBehaviors($this->behaviors());
}
```

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/console/CConsoleCommand.php#L65

Comment: Unfair that your reply didn't get accepted as it is the shortest and cleanest possible way. Here's my +1 as a minor replacement

Comment: What if command doesn't have actions and only has a `run` method? What do I use as a first parameter.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
Yii::import('application.commands.*');
$command = new GearmanCommand('start', Yii::app()->commandRunner);
$command->run(array('start', '--daemonize', '--initd'));
```

where array('start', '--daemonize', '--initd') is a action and action parameters

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem - i need to call action from inside controller and from command

I said same problem because it actually same - you have action which you need to call from console, and call it from controller too.

`If you need to call an action(command) as a part of controller action, then i think you need to modify this solution a little`. Or is my solution is enough for you?

So here is my solution:

first create action as said in http://www.yiichina.net/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#action

```
class NotifyUnsharedItemsAction extends CAction
{
    public function run()
    {
        echo "ok";
    }
}
```

then in controller action is loaded as usuall:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{

    public function actions() {
        return array(
            'notifyUnsharedItems'=>'application.controllers.actions.NotifyUnsharedItemsAction',
    );
}
```

and in command i run action in such way:

```
class NotifyUnsharedItemsCommand extends CConsoleCommand
{
    public function run($args)
    {
        $action = Yii::createComponent('application.controllers.actions.NotifyUnsharedItemsAction',$this,'notify');
        $action->run();
    }

}
```

Comment: I need do what you said vise versa.

Comment: ah, i see now. you don't want to do it vice versa, you want to execute it in the way it will not exceed time limit. my answer incorrect then, yes. why don't you run it as a cron job and use saved result in web application then?

Answer (score 2):

Accepting that we are on linux server, for Yii 1.1 real life example would be:

```
$run = '/usr/bin/php ' . Yii::getPathOfAlias('root').'/yiic' [command]
exec(sprintf("%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s", $run, '/dev/null', '/dev/null'));
```

This will run Yii console command in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Yii is PHP -> you can use the standard php constructs specified at http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php and the related methods near the bottom of the page, depending on what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: I need to know how to execute an action of a CConsoleCommand.

Answer (score 1):

Also, another very clean solution from `cebe` on [gist](https://gist.github.com/cebe/2126943):

```
<?php
// ...
$runner=new CConsoleCommandRunner();
$runner->commands=array(
    'commandName' => array(
        'class' => 'application.commands.myCommand',
    ),
);

ob_start();
$runner->run(array(
    'yiic',
    'idbrights',
));
echo nl2br(htmlentities(ob_get_clean(), null, Yii::app()->charset));

Yii::app()->end();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction! Though I followed the wiki post to actually get it working for me http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/226/run-yiic-directly-from-your-app-without-a-shell/

Answer (score 0):

Typically what you should do in these situations is refactor.
Move the "common" code out of the MyCommand and place it into a class located in the `components` folder.
Now you can place any head on top of the "common" code without altering your functionality. For example:

protected/components/Mywork.php:

```
<?php
class Mywork
{
    public function doWork()
    {
        $model = new Product();
        $model->title = 'my product';
        ...
        $model->save();
        ...
    }
}
```

protected/controller/MyworkController.php:

```
<?php
class MyworkController
{
    public function actionDowork()
    {
        $mywork = new Mywork;
        ...
    }
}
```

protected/commands/MyworkCommand.php:

```
<?php
class MyworkCommand extends CConsoleCommand
{
    public function run($args)
    {
        $mywork = new Mywork;
        ...
    }
}
```

This approach makes testing easier too as you can test Mywork as a single unit outside of the view you are using.