# CConsoleCommand how to execute from URL

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I have a yii CConsoleCommand script in "commands" folder, and i want to execute the command from URL, and not only from cronjob.

any idea how can i do it?

my cron job is:

```
protected/yiic.php myscript
```

my script is:

```
  class MyscriptCommand extends CConsoleCommand {
        public function run() {
    }}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a console command in web application action in Yii?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151887/how-to-call-a-console-command-in-web-application-action-in-yii)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Yii Wiki on this topic: [Run Yiic directly from your app without a shell](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/226/run-yiic-directly-from-your-app-without-a-shell/)