# How to run console command in yii2 from web

Tags: php, shell, cron, console, yii2

I have created a console command in `console/controllers` with `SuggestionController` .

If i run command like `php yii suggestions`, its working.

I want to know how to execute console command from web without any extensions of `yii2`.

Comment: Maybe try `exec()`, but it's generally bad idea.

Comment: https://github.com/toriphes/yii2-console-runner is doing exactly what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I call a console command in web application in Yii 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355483/how-can-i-call-a-console-command-in-web-application-in-yii-2-0)

Comment: console runner returns 1 but not executing the console command

Comment: If i execute shell_exec(php yii suggestions); iam getting could not open input file yii.

Comment: shell_exec('php /var/www/html/portal/yii suggestions');  working for me :) . portal is a root directory for my yii2 application , suggestions is a controller in console/controllers/SuggestionsController.php .

Answer (score 10):

**It can be done much simpler**

```
$oldApp = \Yii::$app;
new \yii\console\Application([
    'id' => 'Command runner',
    'basePath' => '@app',
    'components' => [
        'db' => $oldApp->db,
    ],
);
\Yii::$app->runAction('migrate/up', ['migrationPath' => '@yii/rbac/migrations/', 'interactive' => false]);
\Yii:$app = $oldApp;
```

**[Github LINK](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1764)**

Answer (score 5):

**As of Yii2 - 2.0.11.2 advanced app -- this works**

First let's make sure controller and namespace correct. In this case frontend app accessing console application import method()

In console\controllers\FhirController

[image]

Set the alias to be available in the console\config\main.php [OPTIONAL]

[image]

```
'aliases' => [
    '@common' => dirname(__DIR__),
    '@frontend' =>  dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/frontend',
    '@backend' =>  dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/backend',
    '@console' =>  dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/console',
],
```

Finally from the frontend view, make the call like this:
In this case, calling the controller route fhir then method import()

```
$consoleController = new console\controllers\FhirController('fhir', Yii::$app); 
$consoleController->runAction('import');
```

Answer (score 3):

On a site I'm overhauling, I have a need for a background task, that can be toggled via an action, which requires that I can also find its pid using ps.  After much googling and almost as much swearing, I pieced together the solution.

```
# First change to (already-calculated) correct dir:
chdir($strPath);

# Now execute with nohup, directed to dev/null, and crucially with & at end, to run async:
$output = shell_exec("nohup php yii <console controller>/<action> > /dev/null &");
```

Yes, I understand that shell_exec should be used with extreme caution, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is way I found and used some time ago to run yii console controller/action (I used this for run migrations from web).

In your web controller action:

```
// default console commands outputs to STDOUT
// so this needs to be declared for wep app
if (! defined('STDOUT')) {
    define('STDOUT', fopen('/tmp/stdout', 'w'));
}

$consoleController = new \yii\console\controllers\SuggestionController;
$consoleController->runAction('your action eg. index');

/**
* open the STDOUT output file for reading
*
* @var $message collects the resulting messages of the migrate command to be displayed in a view
*/
$handle = fopen('/tmp/stdout', 'r');
$message = '';
while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
$message .= $buffer . "\n";
}
fclose($handle);

return $message;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the simplest solution:

```
$controller = new SuggestionController(Yii::$app->controller->id, Yii::$app);
$controller->actionSuggestions();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either `exec()` your command ´´´php yii suggestions´´´ but this may result in permission issues with the webserver user.

The better way is to use a ConsoleRunner extension, e.g. [yii2-console-runner](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-console-runner/)  or [yii2-console-runner-extension](https://github.com/vova07/yii2-console-runner-extension) which do the job control job a little bit more sophisticated and more secure with `popen()`.

Always be aware of code injections when executing `exec()` and the like!

Comment: now it run on root folter. so how can i exec in another folder.

Answer (score 0):

yii2 call console command from web or api .

my controller name  :

> UnitController

in folder

> console/controllers

my action name :

> actionUnitDesc

```
    if(!defined('STDIN'))  define('STDIN',  fopen('php://stdin',  'rb'));
    if(!defined('STDOUT')) define('STDOUT', fopen('php://stdout', 'wb'));
    if(!defined('STDERR')) define('STDERR', fopen('php://stderr', 'wb'));
    $consoleController = new \console\controllers\UnitController('unit', Yii::$app);
    $consoleController->runAction('unit-des');
```