# Yii2 Basic:Run Command from Controller Action

Tags: console, yii2, yii2-basic-app

How can I run a command from controller action in basic template?

I tried [How to run console command in yii2 from web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34264442/how-to-run-console-command-in-yii2-from-web)

This fails:

```
public function actionTest(){
    $oldApp = \Yii::$app;
    $console = new \yii\console\Application([
        'id' => 'basic-console',
        'basePath' => '@app/commands',
        'components' => [
            'db' => $oldApp->db,
        ],
    ]);
    \Yii::$app->runAction('hello/index');
    \Yii::$app = $oldApp;
}
```

The above shows me `Unknown command: hello/index Did you mean "help/index"?`

The Command:

```
<?php
/**
 * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
 * @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
 */

namespace app\commands;

use yii\console\Controller;

/**
 * This command echoes the first argument that you have entered.
 *
 * This command is provided as an example for you to learn how to create console commands.
 *
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class HelloController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * This command echoes what you have entered as the message.
     * @param string $message the message to be echoed.
     */
    public function actionIndex($message = 'hello world')
    {
        echo $message . "\n";

    }

}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening for two reasons.

1. You didn't set the `'controllerNamespace'` to `'app\commands'`.
2. The value of `'basePath'` is wrong. If you're running this from the SiteController the value should be `__DIR__ . '/../'`

I recommend doing it a bit different. Again, lets say you're running it from SiteController, I would do it like this:

```
    $config  = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/console.php');
    $console = new \yii\console\Application($config);
```

This way you'll use the same config as when running `./yii hello/index`