# Calling yii2 console/controller inside frontend/controllers

Tags: php, yii2, console-application, yii2-advanced-app

I want to be able to trigger a console controller within my frontend/controllers namespace and also be able to pass alongside some parameters so that the request runs at the background with meddling with whatever the user is doing on the frontend.

Here is my console command

```
<?php
namespace console\controllers;

use common\models\ApplicationStat;
use Yii;
use yii\console\Controller;
use yii\console\ExitCode;

class CronController extends Controller
{
    public $ain_number;
    public $din_number;
    public $userId;

    public function actionVerifyIdentity()
    {
        $model = new IdentityVerification();
        $model->applicant_id = $this->userId;
        $model->ain_status = $this->ain_number;
        $model->din_status = $this->din_number;
        $model->save();

        return ExitCode::OK;

    }

}
```

Within my frontend/controllers action, I am calling the snippet below to trigger the actionVerifyIdentity() in the console controller.

```
Yii::$app->runAction('cron/verify-identity', [
                'din_number' => 1611515151,
                'ain_number' => 118818181,
                'userId' => 7893
            ]);
```

How can I achieve this as what I wrote above is showing page not found and apparently it looks as if it can only working within the console folder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run console command in yii2 from web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34264442/how-to-run-console-command-in-yii2-from-web)

Comment: The best way to handle this is to avoid the problem in the first place. If you need to run controller action in another controller action, that indicates architectural issues. You should probably extract logic of `actionVerifyIdentity()` to separate component/helper and use it in both places where you need verify identity.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow @rob006 instructions. But still if you want to use the controller action directly then you can do this way -

```
$identityVerfier = new CronController();
$identityVerfier->applicant_id = 7893;
$identityVerfier->ain_status = 118818181;
$identityVerfier->din_status = 1611515151;
$identityVerfier->actionVerifyIdentity();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `run()` as follow,

```
Yii::$app->run('cron/verify-identity', [
            'din_number' => 1611515151,
            'ain_number' => 118818181,
            'userId' => 7893
        ]);
```

Also, you can make service for these type of scripts it'll become easy to use.